# Visual Studio 2010 Premium - Web Site Runs Painfully Slow - Windows Forms Projects are fine - Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2010

I have a large web site which is running painfully slow.  It makes no difference weather I run in debug mode or not.  Makes no difference if I even have Visual Studio open or not.  Meaning, I can point my browser at the 'built' code, and it still runs just as slow.  I'm talking 50 seconds to load a page.

So, as a test, I created a standalone windows forms app, and run all the code in it that one of my slow web pages runs (All the business object and database calls)  This test app runs in literally less than a second. So that tells me it is the web site environment and or asp.net that is causing this major slow-down.

I'm at a total loss.  I've tried so many things, but nothing makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Generally websites/web apps are slower to render than a native winforms app. Other than that, nobidy can really tell you much without more detail. A profiler is your best friend.

Comment: Without seeing anything, will be hard to know... maybe lot of images? flash? what do you have on your page? database?

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no replacement for some profiling in case of performce problems.

50 seconds is plenty of time - click break in debugger and see what code is doing which will essentially be sort of profiling. Add tracing and see where time is spent.

Comment: I have already done that.  All of the code takes a long time to run.  As I stated - I took the exact same code and called it from a stand alone Windows forms app, and it runs in less than a second.  So, clearly it is not the code, but a product of the environment.